# SQL query won't count NULL value and shows 0 in result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the total of each discipline however my NULL value still shows 0

I confirmed that there are at least 50 records that has NULL value

what cause the issue here?  below is my code

```
SELECT Discipline,count(Discipline) as num
    FROM table A AS [M]
        RIGHT JOIN        
           table B
         AS [P]
            ON [M].column1 = P.column1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT JOIN table C AS [L]
            ON [L].column1 = [P].column1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [KEY_ID] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS [RN]
            FROM table D
           
        ) AS [S]
            ON [S].ID = [L].ID
               AND [S].[RN] = 1
              
    GROUP BY 
             [M].[Discipline]
```

The result im getting is down below

[image]

I dont know why NULL has 0 count   it should has at least 50 as num

Comment: Did you try count(*)? Count(discipline) wouldn't count nulls. It is already documented, no?

Comment: Counting a column Specifically and Expressly ignores NULL values. So, just don't use that? Count rows instead; `COUNT(*)`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL() Would solve the problem.

```
SELECT Discipline,count(ISNULL(Discipline,0)) as num
    FROM table A AS [M]
        RIGHT JOIN        
           table B
         AS [P]
            ON [M].column1 = P.column1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT JOIN table C AS [L]
            ON [L].column1 = [P].column1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [KEY_ID] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS [RN]
            FROM table D
           
        ) AS [S]
            ON [S].ID = [L].ID
               AND [S].[RN] = 1
              
    GROUP BY 
             [M].[Discipline]
```